# How to solve delay when end call in Sinch Library?

Tags: android, sinch

I have a problem when used [Sinch library](https://www.sinch.com/downloads/) to call.
I try sample here.

I have user A and user B, use A call to B, B answer. After user A press "**End Call**" and finish activity (it's correct), but user B not finish activity now (usually delay 5 seconds). I think have a problem with `onCallEnded`, but I don't solve. Anyone can help me solve this? 
Thank you very much.

```
private class SinchCallListener implements CallListener {

    @Override
    public void onCallEnded(Call call) {
        CallEndCause cause = call.getDetails().getEndCause();
        Log.d(TAG, "Call ended. Reason: " + cause.toString());
        mAudioPlayer.stopProgressTone();
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.USE_DEFAULT_STREAM_TYPE);
        String endMsg = "Call ended: " + call.getDetails().toString();
        Toast.makeText(CallScreenActivity.this, endMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        endCall();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCallEstablished(Call call) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Call established");
        mAudioPlayer.stopProgressTone();
        mCallState.setText(call.getState().toString());
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCallProgressing(Call call) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Call progressing");
        mAudioPlayer.playProgressTone();
    }

    @Override
    public void onShouldSendPushNotification(Call call, List<PushPair> pushPairs) {
        // Send a push through your push provider here, e.g. GCM
    }

}
```